# Cache invalidation through a setter or service?

Tags: java, caching, setter

I've recently had to implement a cache invalidation system, and ended up hesitating between several ways of doing it.

I'd like to know what the best practice is in my case. I have a classic java back-end, with entities, services and repositories.

Let's say I have a `Person` object, with the usual setters and getters, persisted in a database.

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

A `PersonRepository`, instance of `JpaRepository<Person, Long>`.

```
public class PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    public Person save(Person person) {return super.save(person);}
    public Person find(Person person) {return super.find(person);}
    public void delete(Person person) {super.delete(person);}
}
```

I have a `PersonService`, with the usual `save()`, `find()`, `delete()` methods and other more functional methods.

```
public class PersonService {
    public Person save(Person person) {
        doSomeValidation(person)
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I also have so jobs that run periodically and manipulate the `Person` objects. One of which is running every second and uses a cache of `Person` objects, that needs to be rebuilt only if the `firstName` attribute of a Person has been modified elsewhere in the application.

```
public class EverySecondPersonJob {
    private List<Person> cache;

    private boolean cacheValid;
    public void invalidateCache() {
        cacheValid = false;
    }

    public void execute() { // run every second
        if (!cacheValid)
            cache = buildCache();
        doStuff(cache);
    }
}
```

There are lots of places in the code that manipulate Person objects and persist them, some may change the firstName attribute, requiring an invalidation of the cache, some change other things, not requiring it, for example:

```
public class ServiceA {
    public void doStuffA(Person person) {
        doStuff();
        person.setFirstName("aaa");
        personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public void doStuffB(Person person) {
        doStuff();
        person.setLastName("aaa");
        personService.save(person);
    }
}
```

What is the best way of invaliding the cache?

**First idea:**

Create a `PersonService.saveAndInvalidateCache()` method then check every method that calls `personService.save()`, see if they modify an attribute, and if yes, make it call `PersonService.saveAndInvalidateCache()` instead:

```
public class PersonService {
    public Person save(Person person) {
        doSomeValidation(person)
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public Person saveAndInvalidateCache(Person person) {
        doSomeValidation(person)
        Person saved = personRepository.save(person);
        everySecondPersonJob.invalidateCache();
        return saved;
    }
    ...
}

public class ServiceA {
    public class doStuffA(Person person) {
        doStuff();
        person.setFirstName("aaa");
        personService.saveAndInvalidateCache(person);
    }

    public class doStuffB(Person person) {
        doStuff();
        person.setLastName("aaa");
        personService.save(person);
    }
}
```

It requires lots of modifications and makes it error prone if doStuffX() are modified or added. Every doStuffX() has to be aware if they must invalidate or not the cache of an entirely unrelated job.

**Second idea:**

Modify the setFirstName() to track the state of th ePerson object, and make PersonService.save() handle the cache invalidation:

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private boolean mustInvalidateCache;

    setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.mustInvalidateCache = true;
    }
    ...
}

public class PersonService {
    public Person save(Person person) {
        doSomeValidation(person);
        Person saved = personRepository.save(person);
        if (person.isMustInvalidateCache)
            everySecondPersonJob.invalidateCache();
    }
    ...
}
```

That solution makes it less error prone by not making every doStuffX() need to be aware of if they must invalidate the cache or not, but it makes the setter do more than just change the attribute, which seems to be a big nono.

Which solution is the best practice and why?

Thanks in advance.

Clarification: My job running every second calls, if the cache is invalid, a method that retrieves the `Person` objects from the database, builds a cache of other objects based upon the properties of the `Person` objects (here, firstName), and doesn't modify the `Person`.

The job then uses that cache of other objects for its job, and doesn't persist anything in the database either, so there is no potential consistency issue.

Answer (score 0):

**1) You don't**

In the usage scenario you described the best practice is not to do any self grown caching but use the cache inside the JPA implementation. A lot of JPA implementations provide that (e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink, Datanucleus, Apache OpenJPA).

> Now I also have so jobs that run periodically and manipulate the Person objects

You would never manipulate a cached object. To manipulate, you need a session/transaction context and the database JPA implementation makes sure that you have the current object.

If you do "invalidation", as you described, you loose transactional properties and get inconsistencies. What happens if a transaction fails and you updated the cache with the new value already? But if you update the cache after the transaction went through, concurrent jobs read the old value.

**2) Different Usage Scenario with Eventual Consistent View**

You could do caching "on top" of your data storage layer, that provides an eventual consistent view. But you cannot write data back into the same object.
JPA always updates (and caches) the complete object.

Maybe you can store the data that your "doStuff" code derives in another entity?

If this is a possibility, then you have several options. I would "wire in" the cache invalidation via JPA triggers or the "Change Data Capture" capabilities of the database. JPA triggers are similar to your second idea, except that you don't need that all code is using your `PersonService`. If you run the tigger inside the application, your application cannot have multiple instances, so I would prefer getting change events from the database. You should reread everything from time to time in case you miss an event.

Comment: Considering the rest of the application, the hibernate cache isn't really suited here.
Also, to be more precise, my job that is using cached data is not using cached Person objects. It retrieves them from the database, builds a list of objects based on some of their properties (in that example, firstName), and uses that list. It doesn't persist anything in the database, so there is no consistency issue.

Comment: Yep, that's why I added the second part.

Comment: Indeed, that looks like a good solution, I'll look into it. But for the sake of argument, assuming I don't/can't use it, which if the two methods is the best? Would using the setter one be a bad practice?

Comment: You can combine your second idea with a JPA trigger. Keep in mind that `mustInvalidateCache` is a transient field and not persistent, otherwise you need to see how it gets reset. As you say yourself, your first approach is error prone. As always: It depends! Try to keep things simple and go with the first variant but simply always invalidate the cache in case the person changes.

Comment: Keep in mind that you simply could store the old state of the person in the cache, well, you have it anyways. Let the caching service get all the update events, compare whether its a relevant change and then trigger a recalculation of the cached data if needed. This way you have a better separation of concerns.

Comment: And don't forget a + :)